# Python Get Sum of first Column in CSV to Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the sum of the first column in a csv file (has no header). Then I would like to write the sum to a Pandas dataframe as a variable. Here's what I have so far.

```
file_name = "amounts.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name,delimiter='\t').dropna()
amounts = df[0].sum()
print(amounts)
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have so far?

Comment: Get this error among others.

`File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2525, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc`

Comment: 1.`read_csv` should have `headers=None` if your csv file doesn't have headers. 2. Do you really want to `dropna()`, because an `na` in column 2 may remove some data in column 0.

Comment: 3. `df.iloc[:, 0].sum()`

Comment: Thanks Quang Hoang!

'file_name = "amounts.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name,delimiter='\t',header=None)
amounts = df.iloc[:, 0].sum()
print(amounts)'

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name = "amounts.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name,delimiter='\t',header=None)
amounts = df.iloc[:, 0].sum()
print(amounts)
```